# How to navigate into a section inside another component in React?

Tags: reactjs

**I have a component called Signup , inside I have a button which should direct me to a section inside another component **

*Here's my button code *

```
<div className="btn1">
      <Link to="/Navbar/#loginsec">
        <Button
          style={{ display : "block" ,textDecoration: "none", listStyle: "none" }}
          fullWidth
          disableElevation
          variant="contained"
          onClick={() => {
            validate();
          }}
        >
          GO !!
        </Button>
      </Link>
    </div>
```

*I added to the path in the 'Link' the id of that section because I read that it could work *

**Here's my section code **

```
  <section id="loginsec" className={showSignIn ? "signUp active" : "signUp"}>
    <div className="signIn-overlay" onClick={show}></div>
    <div className="container__form">
      <Alert
        className={authfailed ? "active" : ""}
        severity="error"
        onClose={() => {
          SetAuthFailed(false);
        }}
      >
        Authentication failed - try again!
      </Alert>
```

*Still a lot of code left but I grabbed the necessary bit *

Answer (score 0):

You need to install this package 'react-router-hash-link'

You have to use this Hash Link as the Link like below.

```
import { HashLink as Link } from 'react-router-hash-link';
```

Comment: I used HashLink but since it won't work when imported like this 'import {HashLink as Link } from 'react-router-hash-link'   I just kept import {HashLink } but still didn't work

Comment: Please follow this: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/394#issuecomment-220221604